# 64 bit Media Server in Nexus 9

Tags: android, 64-bit, android-5.0-lollipop, stagefright

Nexus 9 is claimed as 64bit device, But all media libs are 32 bit like `mediaserver`, `stagefright`, `OMX`, `MediaPlayerservice` etc . Can anyone help me to know why it is like that ? I need to make them 64 bit, How can I do this ?
Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 3):

In current `AOSP` stack, there are portions of code which require development from vendors like `OMX` or have dependencies on public libraries like `widevine` libs. As not all parts of code are handled by Google and not all have been migrated completely, current code has enabled 32-bit code for the `media` related portions.

To enable complete `64-bit` build, please do the following changes and recompile the entire `AOSP` platform. Please **note** that the underlying assumption is that the rest of the platform has been migrated to `64-bit` already:

1. Enable 64-bit `mediaserver` by disabling [this line](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/mediaserver/Android.mk#44).
2. Enable 64-bit `MediaPlayerService` by disabling [this line](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libmediaplayerservice/Android.mk#60).
3. After migrating your underlying `OMX` components to `64-bit`, add a line in `Android.mk` of `libstagefright` to enable `32-bit` build for specific cases only. The relevant macro for `ACodec` and `OMXCodec` is `OMX_ANDROID_COMPILE_AS_32BIT_ON_64BIT_PLATFORMS`
4. The headers for `OMX` also have to be compiled accordingly in `frameworks/native` as [here](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/native/include/media/openmax/OMX_Types.h#216). Please ensure that true `64-bit` build is enabled.
5. Enable 64-bit `medialoggerservice` by disabling [this line](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/av/services/medialog/Android.mk#11).
6. If you wish to work with `drmserver`, disable [this line](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/av/drm/drmserver/Android.mk#42) for `64-bit` build.

With these changes, you should be able to work with `64-bit` `mediaserver`. This list **doesn't** include `SurfaceFlinger` or `RS` which I hope would be taken care of accordingly.